# Cannot calibrate indoor run for Apple Watch 6

Tags: apple-watch

How can I calibrate the Apple Watch 6 manually so that the indoor running estimation gets more accurate ? I run a little faster than average, so it underestimates about 300 meters per kilometer. That sucks. I have all the settings correct for using outdoor runs as a data foundation for calibration (I have a lot of runs), but it doesn't make much of a difference. Maybe I move a little bit differently on the treadmill and obtain a more stable posture with more of a constant speed with flat and nice elevation compared to a more up and down all the time environment outside. I don't know. Is it possible to do this manually now ? (I know it is not possible on Apple Watch 2, but I was sure that it was going to be possible now ... It's 2020 ... duh!). Help.

Comment: Interesting. I’m not sure you can calibrate stride length without the phone and GPS to tune the accelerometer. Any chance you can pair your watch with a treadmill that would more accurately get you a distance measure? In the end, it probably doesn’t matter. You will expend different energy indoors on a treadmill than you would outdoors, so the calories are going to not follow distance anyhow.

Comment: Calories ? I am not interested in calories, but distance and time spent on that distance (combined with HR)

Comment: It's no fun having measures saying I have spent more time on a distance than I actually have. But hey! Who cares, right ??

Comment: Are you running on a treadmill or on a track? The distance is zero in the former case. Track heart rate and footfalls and time perhaps?

Comment: I am running on a treadmill. You are saying that the distance is zero when running on a treadmill ? Sounds very smart.

Comment: Wow. You’re actually trying to argue / insult with someone trying to help? (And the only person who voted your post up) I’ll wish you well and hope you find an answer you like. Just read the code of conduct as your language should have warned me off from trying to help in the first place.

Comment: Argue, how ? I just want to find out how I can calibrate the watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no manual calibration. You can hope that your indoor stride matches your outdoor stride and use it to refine the step lengths.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204516

The system calculates stride length based on GPS and pace, so if you’re is off, resetting the existing calibration and repeating the outdoor calibration in straight line / flat conditions might be worthwhile.

Comment: it doesn't help to reset